# format statement in string resource file usage

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml

I have this defined in strings.xml

```
<string name="avg"> AVG %1$s</string>
```

And in my code if I want to use it to define AVG HR and just AVG

```
String.format(context.getString(R.string.avg), context.getString(R.string.hr))
```

for defining AVG can I use it as

```
String.format(context.getString(R.string.avg))
```

or should I always do this

```
String.format(context.getString(R.string.avg), " ")
```

Comment: What you want to do exactly? Can you please elaborate? i can help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no need to use `String.format`. `getString` method already supports formatting.

So for instance:

```
 ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(getString(R.string.avg, "hr"));
```

Will results with

> AVG hr

And

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(getString(R.string.avg, ""));
```

Will results with

> AVG

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `String.format()`
Suppose you have the below strings in `strings.xml`

```
<string name="sample">AVG %1$s</string>
<string name="sample2">HR</string>
```

Then you can format `R.string.sample` as either

```
getString(R.string.sample, getString(R.string.sample2)) // AVG HR
```

or

```
 getString(R.string.sample, "") //AVG
```

and yes you have to pass `""` if you don't have value to be appended

Comment: Actually `getString(R.string.sample)` will result in `AVG %1$s`